# why does code following a== type(int) not print even though a is an integer?

Tags: python, integer

This is very basic but somehow I can't seem to get it;

```
a = 12345

if a == type(int): 
    print(True)
```

I also tried replacing int with float, but nothing prints- any idea why??

is a not an integer or float??

Comment: try to print type(int) , a and type(a)

Comment: Try `if type(a)==int`

Comment: @not_speshal Less wrong, but still not what you should write.

Comment: But, you *would* expect that: ‘a == 12345’ to be true.

Comment: `a` is a user-defined name referring to a value of type `int`. `int` is a built-in name referring to a value of type `type`. Those two values are *never* equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
if isinstance(a, int):
```

What you are doing is comparing an `int` value to the type of the *type* `int`; `12345 == type` is never going to be true.